# How do I create a button that when clicked, expands into a body of plots or text?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to create a series of buttons that when clicked, expands into a plot of body of text. Not sure how to go about making this.

[Figma Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6r3E.png)

Comment: Please see, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check android expandable listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved this using an external library: [ExpandableLayout](https://github.com/skydoves/ExpandableLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need to worry, you can just put all of your views inside a parent layout (it works as button) and you set their visibility to **GONE**, then when the parent is clicked you change their visibility to **VISIBLE** for example:

```
--Parent---
          |---View 1: Visible (your title or text...)
          |---View 2: Gone 
          |---View 3: Gone
          |.... other views are all gone
```

when Parent is clicked:

```
--Parent---
          |---View 1: Visible (your title or text...)
          |---View 2: Visible
          |---View 3: Visible
          |.... other views are all visible
```

you can achieve that easily by:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```